# How to change kscreen backend (or disable kscreen)?

Tags: kde, xrandr, plasma5

I'm running KDE on Arch Linux.

```
4.17.5-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Jul 8 17:27:31 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
plasmashell 5.13.3
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.11.1 in /usr/lib
```

I would like to manage my screens with arandr and xrandr instead of kscreen, but I cannot remove kscreen because of dependencies. I also do not see an option or config setting to disable kscreen. However, I did see that there are multiple kscreen backends and one has the name KSC_Fake.so.

```
$  /usr/bin/kscreen-doctor --info
Environment: 
  * KSCREEN_BACKEND           : [not set]
  * KSCREEN_BACKEND_INPROCESS : [not set]
  * KSCREEN_LOGGING           : [not set]
Logging to                : [logging disabled]
Preferred KScreen backend : KSC_XRandR.so
Available KScreen backends:
  * KSC_Fake.so: /usr/lib/qt/plugins/kf5/kscreen/KSC_Fake.so
  * KSC_KWayland.so: /usr/lib/qt/plugins/kf5/kscreen/KSC_KWayland.so
  * KSC_QScreen.so: /usr/lib/qt/plugins/kf5/kscreen/KSC_QScreen.so
  * KSC_XRandR.so: /usr/lib/qt/plugins/kf5/kscreen/KSC_XRandR.so
  * KSC_XRandR11.so: /usr/lib/qt/plugins/kf5/kscreen/KSC_XRandR11.so
```

I would also like to know what is the purpose of KSC_Fake.so. If I assign that backend, does it mean that kscreen is effectively disabled?

To enable a different kscreen backend, would I need to set both of these environment variables?

```
export KSCREEN_BACKEND=KSC_Fake.so
export KSCREEN_BACKEND_INPROCESS=KSC_Fake.so
```

Answer (score 2):

You can disable KScreen in the Plasma System Settings under
"Startup and Shutdown" > "Background Services"

Find and uncheck the "KScreen 2" item and stop the service
and click Apply

Should be able to change display settings now using alternative means without interference from Plasma.